# flask login page cannot login with google account

Tags: python, flask, oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am trying to make a login webpage that can login with google through flask_oauthlib, I created credentials in (OAuth client ID) in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ and did relevant setting, could anyone tell me how to solve this problem[image]

Here is code:

```
"""
    google example
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This example is contributed by Bruno Rocha
    GitHub: https://github.com/rochacbruno
"""
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request, jsonify
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['GOOGLE_ID'] = "XXX"
app.config['GOOGLE_SECRET'] = "XXX"
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'development'
oauth = OAuth(app)

google = oauth.remote_app(
    'google',
    consumer_key=app.config.get('GOOGLE_ID'),
    consumer_secret=app.config.get('GOOGLE_SECRET'),
    request_token_params={
        'scope': 'email'
    },
    base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'google_token' in session:
        me = google.get('userinfo')
        return jsonify({"data": me.data})
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return google.authorize(callback=url_for('authorized', _external=True))


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('google_token', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/login/authorized')
def authorized():
    resp = google.authorized_response()
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason=%s error=%s' % (
            request.args['error_reason'],
            request.args['error_description']
        )
    session['google_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
    me = google.get('userinfo')
    return jsonify({"data": me.data})


@google.tokengetter
def get_google_oauth_token():
    return session.get('google_token')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The google login webpage can show normally, but when I click login button, some errors occur.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/flaskSamples/7-FlaskLoginGoogle/app.py", line 54, in authorized
    resp = google.authorized_response()
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_oauthlib/client.py", line 707, in authorized_response
    data = self.handle_oauth2_response(args)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_oauthlib/client.py", line 671, in handle_oauth2_response
    method=self.access_token_method,
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_oauthlib/client.py", line 404, in http_request
    resp = http.urlopen(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)>
```